# A little help writing a Homebrew formula for Apache Nutch?

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to automate the installation of Apache Nutch by writing a Homebrew formula. The official [tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial) requires users to download a TAR.GZ / ZIP from a mirror, extract, cd, run `ant runtime`, and finally, get the binaries into `PATH`. That's a pain to do over and over, so I'm trying to write a Homebrew formula to automate this for fellow Mac users. The trouble is, my formula isn't working for some reason.

When I run `brew install nutch --verbose`, the build process appears to succeed, but the `runtime/` directory is missing from the Cellar, resulting in a failed `brew test nutch`.

Could someone help me debug my [nutch.rb](https://gist.github.com/apennebaker/6270993) install formula?

```
require 'formula'

class Nutch < Formula
  homepage 'http://nutch.apache.org/'
  url 'http://mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache/nutch/2.2.1/apache-nutch-2.2.1-src.tar.gz'
  sha1 'c5d5d535a87d518aad41e89047c1eeb4331b74d2'

  def install
    system "ant runtime"
    prefix.install Dir['runtime/']
    bin.install_symlink prefix/'runtime/local/bin/nutch'
  end

  test do
    system "#{bin}/nutch", "parsechecker", "http://nutch.apache.org/"
  end
end
```